# iframe with 0 height creates a gap

Tags: html, css, iframe

When I add an iframe to directly after the body, it causes a top margin. Can somebody explain this please? The iframe has no height and no margin.

```css
*, html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
iframe {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>
<div style="background: red;">TEST</div>
```

See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLja65pc/1/

Comment: What is the purpose of having an iframe with a height and width to zero?

Comment: There are some webtracking-tools, that create such iframes in the top of the page.

Comment: Strange...but ok! For that it´s usually use javascript!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iframe is an inline element so it will create a line box. The height of the line box will be equal to the line height (~18px for 16px font) or taller (if iframe is taller than font size).

Change the iframe to `display: block` and will create a block box with the desired height.

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

add `display: block;` to iframe

```css
*, html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
iframe {
    margin: 0; 
    display: block;
}
body {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src=""></iframe>
<div style="background: red;">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use display block for iframe css 
Thanks