# How to prevent an inline element container to occupy space when it's content is empty?

Tags: html, css, image

I have and image element wrapped with a div:

```
 <div id="main_image_wrapper">
    <img id="main_image" src="image.jpg" />
 </div>
```

And, It is fine until there is no image to show. When the `image.jpg` does not exist, I still want to preserve the layout (I will use that later in javascript), So the code will be:

```
 <div id="main_image_wrapper">
    <img id="main_image"  />
 </div>
```

I expect this div element does not occupy (vertical) space, But unfortunately, it does. I tried to play with `line-height`:

```
  div#main_image_wrapper{line-height:1px;}
```

or

```
  div#main_image_wrapper{line-height:0;}
```

But the resultant `div` height will not be less than `6px`.

When I use:

```
  img#main_image{display:block;}
```

this extra space will vanish. But I can not use block image in the page layout.

How can I remove this unwanted `6 px` space when the `img` is empty?

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/wnjsytxw/1/ I don't see 6px height in this jsfiddle.

Comment: Similar question about iframes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858989/iframe-with-0-height-creates-a-gap

Comment: @kasperTaeymans I added `background:blue;` to the css, so the problem reveals itself.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans see: http://jsfiddle.net/wnjsytxw/2/

Comment: yes, I see. Just add the style `display:block;` to your image. see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can hide images without a src:

```
img:not([src]) {
   display: none;
}
```

Technically, an `img` without `src` attribute isn't valid though. There are ways around this, as is discussed in the question [What's the valid way to include an image with no src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src). But if you change that, you will also need to change the CSS, of course. :)

To solve this problem, use this valid html:

```
 <div id="main_image_wrapper">
    <img id="main_image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="  />
  </div>
```

and by the following `css`, prevent occupying space:

```
 img#main_image[src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="]
             {display:none;}
```

Comment: @Golez Excelent solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a different class, say `noImg`, for that case?

```
div.noImg {
  display: none;
}
```

Edit: I assume you are editing the div / img with Javascript, otherwise you wouldn't quite be able to edit the `src` attribute of the `img` element, right?

Comment: Thanks, Yes later i edit the `src` it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you. Just use space after image tag like
`&nbsp;` and then you can play with line height;

```css
#main_image_wrapper{
    border:1px solid blue;
    lineheight:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_image_wrapper">
    <img id="main_image"  /> &nbsp;
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps a bit but with line-height:0; the div still occupies  a samll space.

Comment: Ok so you want 0 height div, then remove space and line height and use display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/wnjsytxw/3/)

css

```
#main_image_wrapper{
    border:1px solid blue;
    background:blue;
}
img{
    display: block;
}
```

html

```
 <div id="main_image_wrapper">
    <img id="main_image"  />
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But as i mentioned earlier, `display:block` does not suit me.